# Intro to Java Parrot Program

Tags: java

We have an assignment for an intro to java class im taking that requires us to program a parrot.

Essentially we have an output
" What do you want to say?

The User types in his input
" Blah Blah Blah"

And then the parrot is supposed to repeat

"Blah Blah Blah"

I have achieved this.

```
package parrot;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Parrot {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(" What do you want to say? ");


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String Parrot = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Paulie Says: " + Parrot);



    }
}
```

This gives me the exact results I need, but then I read in the lab instructions it wants us to do it in 2 files?

```
 Add 2 files to the project: Parrot.java and ParrotTest.java
 In Parrot.java do the following:
 Create a public class called Parrot
 Inside the class create a public method called speak. The method speak has one String          parameter named word and no return value (i.e. return type void) The method header looks     like this: public void speak(String word)
 The parrot repeats anything he is told. We implement this behavior by printing the   word passed as an argument
```

And what I think im being asked to do is call it from another file? Can someone explain to me how to do this as im not exactly sure whats going on?

Comment: Put members and method of class `Parrot` in one file (class name have to be the same of file name), and the `main()` method alone in a class `ParrotTest`.

Comment: your class name and the String have the same name! Change the string name to "parrot"

Answer (score 1):

Yes your program performs the given task, but not in the manner you are asked. Your main method should be executed from inside the ParrotTest.java file. In this file (ParrotTest.java), you will need to create an instance of a class (you can call it Parrot) by calling a constructor.

Inside your Parrot.java you will create a method called 'speak' which accepts String word.

Going back to the main method: Here you will ask for user input, capture the input in a String 'word' and pass it as an argument to the speak method you created. Once your method has this argument, you can print it's content out to the console.

Comment: Ive created the the Main Method and have the scanner set up to prompt the user for the information, how do I pass the information the user inputs to the other method created?

Comment: Parrot parrot = new Parrot(user argument variable);

Answer (score 0):

Parrot would have the following

```
public class Parrot
{
   public void speak( String word )
  {
     System.out.printf("%s", word);
  }
}
```

Parrot Test would have the following

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ParrotTest
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
      {
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.print("What would you like to say to the parrot?: ");

   String words = input.nextLine();

   Parrot myParrot = new Parrot();
   myParrot.speak(words);
      }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have to use scanner but this is how i would do it.BTW this code works with Jcreator.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String say = IO.getString("Say something") // This is asking the user to say something

System.out.print(name);
}


If you want it to loop 10 times then
then do this




public static void main(String[] args) {
String say = IO.getString("Say something"); // This is asking the user to say something
int count = 10; // it will loop 10 times
while (count >= 10) {
System.out.print(name);
say = IO.getString("Say something");
count++;
```

}

By the way if you don't have IO class you can you this. Just copy this code into jcreator and say it where you save all your codes.

```
/**
 * @(#)IO.java
 * This file is designed to allow HCRHS students to collect information from the
 * user during Computer Science 1 and Computer Science 2.
 * @author Mr. Twisler, Mr. Gaylord
 * @version 2.01 2014/12/21
 *      *Updated fix to let \t work for all input/output
 *      *Added input methods to allow for console input
 *      *Allowed all get methods to work with all objects
 *      *Updated format methods to use String.format()
 */

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class IO {

    // Shows a message in a popup window
    public static void showMsg(Object obj) {
        JTextArea text = new JTextArea(obj.toString());
        text.setBorder(null);
        text.setOpaque(false);
        text.setEditable(false);
        //String text = obj.toString().replace("\t", "     ");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, text, "HCRHS", 
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }

/*********************************User Input Methods***************************
 * All user input methods get the data type mentioned in their name and return
 * a default value if the user enters an incorrect responce.
 ******************************************************************************/

    // Returns String typed by user, default value is ""
    public static String getString(Object obj) {
        JTextArea text = new JTextArea(obj.toString());
        text.setBorder(null);
        text.setOpaque(false);
        text.setEditable(false);
        //String text = obj.toString().replace("\t", "     ");
        String ans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, text, "HCRHS",
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        if(ans == null) {
             return "";
        }
        return ans;
    }

    public static String nextString() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ans = scan.nextLine();
        scan.close();
        if(ans == null) {
             return "";
        }
        return ans;
    }

    // Returns int typed by the user, default value is 0
    public static int getInt(Object obj) {
        JTextArea text = new JTextArea(obj.toString());
        text.setBorder(null);
        text.setOpaque(false);
        text.setEditable(false);
        //String text = obj.toString().replace("\t", "     ");
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, text, 
                    "HCRHS", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            //System.out.println("Not a valid int");    
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static int nextInt() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ans;
        try {
            ans = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            //System.out.println("Not a valid int");    
            ans = 0;
        }
        scan.close();
        return ans;
    }  

    // Returns double typed by the user, default value is 0.0
    public static double getDouble(Object obj) {
        JTextArea text = new JTextArea(obj.toString());
        text.setBorder(null);
        text.setOpaque(false);
        text.setEditable(false);
        //String text = obj.toString().replace("\t", "     ");
        try {
            return Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, text, 
                        "HCRHS", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
        } catch (NumberFormatException|NullPointerException e) {
            //System.out.println("Not a valid double");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static double nextDouble() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double ans;
        try {
            ans = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
        } catch (NumberFormatException|NullPointerException e) {
            //System.out.println("Not a valid double");
            ans = 0;
        }
        scan.close();
        return ans; 
    }

    // Returns char typed by the user, default value is ' '
    public static char getChar(Object obj) {
        JTextArea text = new JTextArea(obj.toString());
        text.setBorder(null);
        text.setOpaque(false);
        text.setEditable(false);
        //String text = obj.toString().replace("\t", "     ");
        try {
            return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, text, "HCRHS", 
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE).charAt(0);
        } catch (NullPointerException|StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            //System.out.println("Not a valid char");
            return ' ';
        }
    }

    public static char nextChar() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        char ans;
        try {
            ans = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);
        } catch (NullPointerException|StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            //System.out.println("Not a valid char");
            ans = ' ';
        }
        scan.close();
        return ans;
    }

    // Returns boolean typed by the user, default value is false
    public static boolean getBoolean(Object obj) {
        JTextArea text = new JTextArea(obj.toString());
        text.setBorder(null);
        text.setOpaque(false);
        text.setEditable(false);
        //String text = obj.toString().replace("\t", "     ");
        int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, text, "HCRHS", 
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
                    null, new Object[]{"True", "False"}, 1);
        return (n == 0);
    }

    public static boolean nextBoolean() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String bool = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        scan.close();
        if (bool.equals("true") || bool.equals("t") || bool.equals("1")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

/******************************Formatting Methods******************************
 * Format is overloaded to accept Strings/int/double/char/boolean
 ******************************************************************************/

    public static String format(char just, int maxWidth, String s)  {
        if (just == 'l' || just == 'L') {
            return String.format("%-" + maxWidth + "." + maxWidth + "s", s);
        } else if (just == 'r' || just == 'R') {
            return String.format("%" + maxWidth + "." + maxWidth + "s", s);
        } else if (just == 'c' || just == 'C') {
            return format('l', maxWidth, format('r', 
                            (((maxWidth - s.length()) / 2) + s.length()), s));
        } else {
            return s;
        }
    }

    public static String format(char just, int maxWidth, int i) {
        return format(just, maxWidth, String.format("%d", i));
    }

    public static String format(char just, int maxWidth, double d, int dec) {
        return format(just, maxWidth, String.format("%,." + dec + "f", d));
    }   

    public static String format(char just, int maxWidth, char c) {
        return format(just, maxWidth, String.format("%c", c));
    }

    public static String format(char just, int maxWidth, boolean b) {
        return format(just, maxWidth, String.format("%b", b));
    }

/*********************************Fancy Expirmental Methods********************/

    public static String choice(String... options) {
        String s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
                        "Pick one of the following", "HCRHS", 
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, null);
        //If a string was returned, say so.
        if ((s != null) && (s.length() > 0)) {
            return s;
        }
        return "";   
    } 

    public static String readFile(String fileName) {
        String ans ="";
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
            scanner.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator")); 
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                ans += scanner.next()+"\n";
            }
            scanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ans;
    }

    public static void writeFile(String fileName, String data) {
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName, true);
            fw.write(data);
            fw.close();
        } catch(java.io.IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```